# To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use git push --set-upstream origin master

Tags: git, git-bash

I am a beginner in git bash but i'm not able to find the meaning of the errors comming when i do git push , i get the error

```
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

until git commit everything works fine and i get all things in git status command but after git push everything seems to be lost .

Screen Shot for reference :
[image]

Comment: How about doing what Git told you to do? Git thinks you should try saying `git push --set-upstream origin master`. Try saying it.

Comment: As @matt says : the second sentence of the message is actually the command you should type : `git push --set-upstream origin master`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

When you use git push it means you are trying to upload your local repository to remote repository which is hosted somewhere online, it could be github, gitlab etc.

In order to upload your code to remote repository you need to set an upstream which means, set a place to push your repository.
you do this by adding the URL of remote repository.

```
git remote add origin url-of-remote #origin becomes the shorthand for the url
```

Once you do this then you easily push your code using `git push -u origin master`